# M:N entity (best) merge strategy

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an M: N relationship example with spring data and JPA. The intermediate table is implement as an entity. I'am looking for good merge strategy.
Use case:
One student can register one or many courses. One courses can be attended by many students.

Now a student has already registered in a course and wants to register in the same course again. On the M:N there is a unique constraint and leads to an error case.

I would like to merge the already registered courses and new unknown courses should be persisted.

Running example can be found [here](https://github.com/MelleD/demo-student-course)

Small example here

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
//  @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
//  @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    public AbstractEntity() {
        id = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    @PersistenceConstructor
    public AbstractEntity(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if (id == null) {
            return super.hashCode();
        }
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        final AbstractEntity other = (AbstractEntity) obj;
        // unsaved objects are never equal
        if (id == null || other.getId() == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return Objects.equals(id, other.id);
    }

}


@Entity
@Table
public class StudentCourse extends AbstractEntity{


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    private Student student;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    private Course course;

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public StudentCourse setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
        return this;
    }

    public Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public StudentCourse setCourse(Course course) {
        this.course = course;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Component
public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private CourseRepository courseRepository;

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Transactional
    public Student mergeStudent(UUID studentId, Set<UUID> courseIds) {
        Student student = studentRepository.findById(studentId).get();

        //check if exist
        List<Course> courses = courseRepository.findAllById(courseIds);
        if (courses.size() != courseIds.size()) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException();
        }

        //TODO what is the best merge strategy have to figure out which course is already registerd and not
        Set<StudentCourse> mergeCourses = courses.stream().map(course -> new StudentCourse().setCourse(course).setStudent(student)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        student.setStudentCourse(mergeCourses);

        return studentRepository.save(student);
    }
}
```

Test case

```
@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private CourseRepository courseRepository;

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired
    private StudentCourseRepository studentCourseRepository;


    @Test
void testMerge() {

    Student student = new Student();
    Course course = new Course();
    Course course2 = new Course();
    Course course3 = new Course();

    Course savedCourse1 = courseRepository.save(course);
    Course savedCourse2 = courseRepository.save(course2);
    Course savedCourse3 = courseRepository.save(course3);
    courseRepository.save(course2);
    student.setStudentCourse(Set.of(new StudentCourse().setCourse(savedCourse1).setStudent(student), new StudentCourse().setCourse(savedCourse3).setStudent(student)));
    Student savedStudent = studentRepository.save(student);

    studentService.mergeStudent(savedStudent.getId(), Set.of(savedCourse1.getId(), savedCourse2.getId()));

    assertThat(studentCourseRepository.findAll()).hasSize(2);
}
```

Off course i can filter the list and build the diffs like:

```
    final Set<StudentCourse> currentStudentCourse = student.getStudentCourse().stream()
            .filter(course -> courseIds.contains(course.getCourse().getId())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    final Set<UUID> currentCourseIds = currentStudentCourse.stream()
            .map(studentCourse -> studentCourse.getCourse().getId()).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    // TODO what is the best merge strategy
    final Set<StudentCourse> mergeCourses = courses.stream()
            .filter(course -> !currentCourseIds.contains(course.getId()))
            .map(course -> new StudentCourse().setCourse(course).setStudent(student)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    mergeCourses.addAll(currentStudentCourse);
    student.setStudentCourse(mergeCourses);
```

Maybe there is a smarter solution.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a ManyToMany relationship?
See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany and https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: You'll also have the following problem: You create new StudentCourses, which have a NULL ID field, so JPA will try to insert them. Since you add them to a Set in Student, it needs the hashCode (and equals) for StudentCourse. Which you have not implemented, so that probably won't do the right thing. But again, when JPA sees a NULL ID field, it will perform an insert. You don't want to create a completely new set - you want to _add_ the ones to the set which aren't in there yet. Sets give you this for free, if your equals/hashCode works correctly.

Comment: For my last comment, see 
https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-equals-and-hashcode/
and 
https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/

Comment: Hey Benjamin thanks for you answer.
Iam not using ManyToMany because I need a real class for the relationship. The ManyToMany class have some properties. This is just a example to show my "issue".
Second of course equal and hashcode is overwritten, but the equals checks the ID (PK). Maybe i should try this version https://web.archive.org/web/20170810065759/http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html?page=2
And i use Primary key for equals check

Comment: Still not 100% sure what you are trying to do: Your test case checks for `studentCourseRepository.findAll()).hasSize(2);` but you save 2 and then you merge with 1 old and 1 new - shouldn't that come out to 3 or do you _also_ want to delete anything not passed as an argument to `merge` (then I would change the name though).

Answer (score 1):

OK, so first, I'd recommend to review [JPA State Transitions](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-hibernate-entity-state-transitions/).
Any Entity with an auto-generated ID that is NULL will be seen as "new" and thus persisted + ID generated. This is not what you want when readding existing StudentCourses.

Let's start with my changes to `Student`:

```
    public void addStudentCourse(StudentCourse sc) {
        this.studentCourse.add(sc);
        sc.getCourse().getStudentCourse().add(sc);
    }

    public void addAllStudentCourses(Iterable<StudentCourse> scs) {
        scs.forEach(this::addStudentCourse);
    }
```

I've added these methods, bc. you are required to keep [bi-directional relationships](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/) in-sync yourself!
(you may also want the inverse for `Course`, but you *must not* call `addStudentCourse` from `Course`, one side has to be in charge and this would recoursively add StudentCourse).

Next, `StudentCourse` (changes only):

```
@Entity
public class StudentCourse {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Student student;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Course course;

    public StudentCourse() {
    }

    public StudentCourse(Student student, Course course) {
        this.student = student;
        this.course = course;
    }

    // This Equals & HashCode only work with course & student being EAGERLY fetched!
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        StudentCourse that = (StudentCourse) o;
        return Objects.equals(student, that.student) && Objects.equals(course, that.course);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(student, course);
    }
}
```

I made sure that `course` and `student` are non-null and can't be changed (think about it - that wouldn't make sense anyway).
This way I can use them in `equals` and `hashCode` safely. This only works bc. they are [EAGER fetched](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/) - which you *normally* do not want, but for this kind of merge entity, it makes sense.
So now we can safely use `StudentCourse` in Hash-based collections.

A small change to `StudentRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT student FROM Student student JOIN FETCH student.studentCourse WHERE student.id = :id")
    Optional<Student> findByIdWithStudentCourses(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

`@OneToMany` associations are LAZY fetched. That is generally a good idea, but for the best performance, you should JOIN FETCH them (i.e., eagerly load them) if **you know that you will use them anyway**.

And in our service, we **do** use it:

```
@Transactional
public Student mergeStudent(Long studentId, Set<Long> courseIds) {
    Student student = studentRepository.findByIdWithStudentCourses(studentId).get();

    //check if exist
    List<Course> courses = courseRepository.findAllById(courseIds);
    if (courses.size() != courseIds.size()) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException();
    }

    // Find *new* student-course-mappings
    Set<StudentCourse> newCourseSubscriptions = new HashSet<>();
    for (Course course : courses) {
        StudentCourse tmp = new StudentCourse(student, course);
        if (!student.getStudentCourse().contains(tmp)) {
            newCourseSubscriptions.add(tmp);
        }
    }

    // Persist new mappings and add them (to student AND course)
    List<StudentCourse> savedSCs = studentCourseRepository.saveAll(newCourseSubscriptions);
    student.getStudentCourse().addAll(savedSCs);

    // No need to call `save`, which doesn't save anything!
    return student;
}
```

So, `merge` is supposed to bring "detached" entities back into the persistence context ("managed" state). If there are any changes, this will update the DB state. This **only works** for detached entities though. E.g., they already have an auto-generated ID. This will **not work** for new, "transient" entities.

What we want to do is simple. We fetch Student with all its StudentCourse mappings and check which ones are new. This will work, because `equals` only looks at `course` and `student` (and their equals should work, too! might want to check that).
This doesn't work if you want to *remove* mappings though. In that case, you'll want to take the already persisted and newly persisted `StudentCourse`s, put them in a set and just replace `Student`'s (`student.setStudentCourse()`).

Now, why did I not put a `studentRepo.save()` in the end?
I could start a whole rant here. Spring Data JPA's `save` is badly named. IT DOESN'T SAVE ANYTHING (for managed entities).
It will call `persist` for new/transient ones and `merge` for managed ones.
But that is not only unnecessary, but potentially bad.

The whole point of JPA is tracking changes. When your entity is "managed", that literally means that Hibernate "manages" it. There is a "dirty tracking" mechanism. When you change a managed entity in some way (setter), Hibernate will track that and call `flush` at a certain point, issuing update statements to the database.

`persist` is for new/transient entities, `merge` for detached ones (i.e., you keep it alive in your program across a transaction boundary, or you get it in some serialized form, e.g., JSON) - but `managed` entities are auto-magic.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and your efforts.
I tried to keep the example as simple as possible to describe the problem.
I have extended the example to generate the ID equals / hashcode and set the relationships. I omitted performance optimization for n + 1. I am aware of the problems.

As far as the code works to merge with already existing StudenCourse. However, I still don't find the solution elegant and complex.
Your solution looks a little simpler, but it only works with the appropriate equals and hashcode method. We are currently using the "based on the primary key approach"